# Will Run H2O on local desktop will speed up calculation?

Tags: h2o

I just start to learn H2O. I am confused about if i run H2O at home just for leaning purpose. When I simply run "h2o.init()" then start data clean or modeling using H2O. Will it speed up the calculation speed for big data? Is it automatically connect to some H2O cluster online? Where is the H2O cluster located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `h2o.init()` (i.e. with no arguments) it will start a "cluster", on that same machine. By default it will be given about a quarter of your machine's memory, and can use either all threads or two threads (the latter is if using R and you installed it from CRAN). You will find Flow listening on `http://127.0.0.1:54321/`

If you already have an H2O cluster running on another machine (whether on your LAN or a distant cloud server), give the address to `h2o.init()` to have it connect to that instead of starting anything locally.

Run `help(h2o.init)` (on Python) or `?h2o.init` (on R) to see all the available options.

NOTE: H2O is a client/server architecture, but the server (also called the "cluster", even if you only have one machine) is where all the action takes place, and where the data and models are kept, and the client is relatively thin. Responding to one of the comments, if you are comparing H2O running localhost to a library like scikit-learn, there is not much difference (in available compute power). The advantage of H2O is that you can easily and transparently add more machines over a LAN, to increase available memory and (to some extent) compute power; and having clients in languages other than R. The disadvantages are mainly around having to remember the server is where your data is kept; e.g. with large data sets use the functions to load it directly into your server, because keeping a copy in the client is just wasting memory.

Comment: If I only have one desktop, does that mean it only run on my desktop? Then will it be faster than not using H2O since it is only using my desktop?

Comment: @Gavin Could you rephrase that? What is the "it" that would be faster than not using H2O?

Comment: I think it make sense if I use H2O connect to some serve or EC2 to leverage the computation power. That can speed up the calculation. But if I only have one local machine without connect to another machine or server. Will running calculation be faster if I use H2O vs do not use H2O? Why? I don't understand what makes H2O faster?

Comment: @Gavin I'm still not really getting what you are asking. H2O is for machine learning. If you don't use H2O you don't get any output. In that sense it is infinitely faster to not use H2O, but infinitely less useful :-)   (As for what makes h2o faster, that depends on which algorithm, and the size of your data. Generally more/faster cores, more memory, make it faster.)

Comment: thanks. I think I understands your answers. The link http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/architecture.html also help me to better understand why H2O is faster.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about why he needs to initiate an H2O server in order to run a machine learning algorithm, as opposed to for example scikit-learn where you don't have a server process running and you just run the code package directly.....

Comment: @MustardTiger Thanks, I just added a paragraph to my answer on that.